# Display message on plugin activation and deactivation in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm building a WordPress plugin and want to display a message on activating the plugin and on its deactivation.

It should display the message one time on the plugins page in the dashboard.

[image: Plugin Message]

I have tried it with `admin_notices` hook but the message continuously displayed.

Can anyone tell me any condition or method to achieve this or any WordPress hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can show the message on activation of your plugin only once.

**Here is how you can do it:**

1) Register a new setting option in your plugin i.e. `plugin_status`

2) Write this code:

```
 function when_my_plugin_activate() {
       if (get_option('plugin_status') != 'active' && !is_plugin_active('your-plugin-folder/your-plugin-file.php')) {
           echo 'Your Message Here!';
           update_option('plugin_status', 'active');
       }
    }

add_action('admin_notices', 'when_my_plugin_activate');
```

3) Here is another code block on deactivation of the plugin to change the status:

```
function when_my_plugin_deactivate() {
    update_option('plugin_status', 'inactive');
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'when_my_plugin_deactivate');
```

Answer (score -1):

add a setting option and when display message change setting value and use `if()`
its deactivation

Comment: Can you add a demo or a simple example?